# I need to install my sql server 5.1 where there is no internet connection

Tags: installation, server, mysql, tar, offline

Please kindly help me at the following issue. Currently I don't have an Internet connection and I need to install MySQL server on Ubuntu 11.04 without any rpm packages. I have only the tar file with me. It has been extracted to the particular area. So what are the command to be used?

Comment: Why are you using rpm packages in ubuntu? Or Tar? Where did you get the tar file from? If its a source package you'd need to compile it

Answer (score 1):

First, Ubuntu is a dpkg-based Linux distribution, not rpm. So use `apt-get` or `dpkg` to install packages.

<del>Second, MySQL 5.5 is much better than 5.1. And the latest Ubuntu release (precise) provides only 5.5 now.</del>
Well, since you have older releases, you can still use 5.1. The package `mysql-server` will always match the latest version of MySQL for your release.

Since you do not have internet, you can run `sudo apt-get install -sV mysql-server` locally without connection. The option `-s` means "dry run" and the option `-V` means "show version number". This command does not require root permission and will not install anything really. It will just show list all the dependencies the package `mysql-server` needs and simulates installing them. Thus you can get both the dependencies, the architectures and the version numbers. You can use a redirection to save them to a text file and copy it to a computer with Internet connection. With this list of packages, you can download them on the computer with Internet and copy them back to the computer without Internet.

On the computer without Internet, you can use `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install all the .deb files you've downloaded from another computer.